# Master Page CSS overwriting Web Form CSS using Master Page

Tags: css, asp.net

***Update***

I had the syntax incorrect ~/Styles/Default.css needed to be /Styles/Default.css

I have a CSS page linked to the master.

Now I created my Default.aspx page that uses the Master Page

In Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" href="~/Styles/Default.css" type="text/css"/>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ContentBanner" ContentPlaceHolderID="banner" runat="server">
    <div id="banner">
        <img src="/Images/Banners/banner.gif" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.css

```
#banner
{
    background-color:#FDFD82;
}
```

In VS I see the background color of that div correctly but when I load it in IE it doesn't show.
If I code the style into the div section and not CSS it works.

What I'm I missing here?

Comment: Sometimes browser caches CSS files, so use Ctrl+F5 in IE to clear cache. If still not working, look at view source of browser, and see the order of CSS files. Does style apply correctly in FF and Chrome too?

Comment: ***I had the syntax incorrect*** - Did you fix the problem or are you still having an issue?

Comment: Yes I got it corrected

Answer (score 0):

visual studio reloads the style sheet, but the browser doesnt, it caches it once and uses it unless you reload it.

so, either press **Ctrl** + **R** in your browser to refresh it and have it reload all the resources, or use a trick which will make the browser reload the style sheet every time:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" href="~/Styles/Default.css?<%=DateTime.Now %>" type="text/css"/>
```

have a look at the link, i appended a query string with the current time. the time changes always, and it makes the browser think its a different sheet, and reload it every time.